# Scheme: CAR and CDR of a list

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, racket

I am confused as to how `car` and `cdr` work on lists.  Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
(define sample (read))
(display sample)
(display (car sample))
(display (cdr sample))
(display (car (cadr sample)))
(display (cdr (cdr sample)))
```

On entering the value `'(A B C D E F)`, here is what I get:

```
'(a b c d e f)
quote
((a b c d e f))
a
()
```

I am not able to understand that how `quote` can be the `car` of `sample`. Also, why does `(cdr sample)` output `((a b c d e f))`?

Language: DrScheme - R5RS - Scheme

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you wanted to simply type the list `(a b c d e f)`, you should just type `(a b c d e f)`.  What you typed, instead, was `(quote (a b c d e f))` because the `'` operator is short for `(quote ...)`.

Your list literally has the first element `quote` and the second element `(a b c d e f)`.  Of course, when you're writing source code, you need the `quote` to prevent the S-expressions from being executed.

Comment: Thank you. I am a complete newbie to Scheme. This helps !